# Assembler and hex dump change when formatting c++ code

Tags: c++, assembly

A C++ project I work on does not have consistent indentation. The lead developer told me it might not be safe to reformat the code. I thought it might not matter to the compiled code. As a test I tried reformatting one file using a Formatter based on the Eclipse "GNU [built-in]" Profile. When I recompiled the file the md5sum changed. I did a hexdump of the file and it showed one byte changed. I disassembled the object file. I also compiled with debugging and I got the source code line. I used diff to get the assembly instruction that changed.

The source was this line

```
        logErr
        << xmlutils.GetErrorMessage() << endl;
```

Below is the diff output showing the changed assembly

```
     23be:  89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
     23c1:  e8 fc ff ff ff          call   23c2 <_ZN12RerouteAdapt11WriteToFileERKSs+0x64>
     23c6:  e8 fc ff ff ff          call   23c7 <_ZN12RerouteAdapt11WriteToFileERKSs+0x69>
-    23cb:  c7 44 24 04 79 01 00    movl   $0x179,0x4(%esp)
+    23cb:  c7 44 24 04 84 01 00    movl   $0x184,0x4(%esp)
     23d2:  00 
     23d3:  89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
     23d6:  e8 fc ff ff ff          call   23d7 <_ZN12RerouteAdapt11WriteToFileERKSs+0x79>
```

The ordering of the headers was not changed by the reformat.

I know some C/C++, but very little about assembly. I was wondering if there was a simple explanation for why the object file would change. I thought the C++ compiler (GCC 4.8.2 on RHEL 7) was indifferent to formatting and white space. There were no differences besides this in the assembly.

Comment: Is that related to line number, or other position in source file? There are a few things like that, which are sensitive to position.

Comment: Changing white space would not change a stack offset, unless the values were inside a string or set of quotes.    Maybe __DATE__ was used and it changed or something?

Comment: @ThomasJager is right.  If this is a "debug" build, then there are debug asserts that include the line number.  If this is on line 377, then that's the issue.

Comment: Many lines in the file changed. The diff output is 1,400. lines. But this is the only instruction that changed. This exact line appears at another location in the file, and was also reformatted. No change in the hex dump.

Comment: The main() file uses __DATE__, but this file does not.

Comment: The first build, the one showing the diff output of the assembly, was without debugging. But that one changed instruction is also visible in a dump of the debug output.

Comment: Tim Roberts comment put me on the right track. I assumed "logErr" was a C++ stream. It is not. It is a macro. I'll edit the question to include. Sorry if my question seems obvious. It's a big project, and I'm not familiar with all the files.

Comment: Please post the answer as an answer, not an edit to the question.  Self-answered questions are encouraged when you have a real answer.  (i.e. that the behaviour of the code depended on source line numbers.)

Answer (score 2):

Thomas and Tim were correct. The value that changed corresponds to the line number before and after formatting. I assumed "logErr" was just a stream. Turns out it is a macro that uses the `__LINE__` macro. So the line number is hard-coded in the assembly.

```
#define logErr theTracer().SetFuncName(__func__); theTracer().SetFile(__FILE__); theTracer().SetLine(__LINE__); theTracer().SetError(); theTracer()
```

Thank you for your help.